# Word for "a person who quickly gets interested and quickly loses interest"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I have googled but didn't find. "A person who gets interested in anything very quickly and loses interest in it sooner." What is such a person called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily a *butterfly mind*, but just a **butterfly**.

butterfly ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/butterfly)):

> **2.** a person who never settles with one group, interest, or occupation for long

butterfly ([MW dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butterfly)):

> **2** : something that resembles or suggests a butterfly; *especially* : a
>   person chiefly occupied with the pursuit of pleasure

butterfly ([dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/butterfly))

> **2** a person who flits aimlessly from one interest or group to another: *a social butterfly*

Answer (score 5):

Such a person is often described as having *a butterfly mind*.

Comment: If possible, please add a corroborating link.

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+butterfly+mind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are hundreds of *butterfly minds*, and I doubt many of them are actually inside a butterfly's head.

Answer (score 1):

One might describe such a person as a [dilettante](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dilettante), in the first sense:-

> a person who takes up an art, activity, or subject merely for
>   amusement, especially in a desultory or superficial way; dabbler.

Comment: I don't think being a *dilettante* necessarily implies you'll quickly lose interest - [I've been a magical dilletante since I was a kid](http://www.themagiccafe.com/forums/viewtopic.php?topic=179649&forum=42) doesn't seem "odd" to me.

Answer (score -1):

Impatient polymath or perfectionist with a short span of attention.

Comment: Those are not single words.