# Adjective that describes a person who shows a lot of enthusiasm in the beginning but gets bored gradually?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

Can anyone provide a word which describes a person who shows a lot of enthusiasm in the beginning but gets bored gradually and eventually leaves the task uncompleted?

I looked at **jaded**, but it doesn't fulfill the criteria.  Jaded seems to describe more of an overworked fellow, whereas the word I'm looking for would describe the nature of person. The word I'm looking for would describe a person who always exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Why doesn't *jaded* fulfil your criteria?

Comment: @MattЭллен jaded is more like an overworked fellow. It doesn't describe the nature of person. I'm talking about a person who always does this.

Comment: I call that "ADHD". But there must be a word for these "starters".

Comment: @Susan a person suffering with "ADHD" would show no interest at all. I'm talking about a person who shows immense interest in the beginning. For example, someone starts learning guitar, practices for 10 hrs a day but after a week quits it.

Comment: Actually you are incorrect about that. Having enthusiasm for starting things but failure to follow through is typical of ADHD. I understand your question, and think it's a good one.

Comment: Well, In my opinion, I woudl say that this describes ME, so the answer is me.

Comment: "Ennui" describes the latter portion of your word request, in regard to boredom. Some definitions emphasize the lack of interest, but dictionary.com says "a feeling of utter weariness and discontent resulting from satiety or lack of interest; boredom. The "resulting from satiety" points out that there was an appetite or enthusiasm beforehand. But, alas, it's a French noun and doesn't suit.

Comment: Similar question:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86795/word-for-a-person-who-quickly-gets-interested-and-quickly-loses-interest

Answer (score 3):

The term **[distractible](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distractible)** can be used to describe someone who is

> subject to distraction

*[Distract](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distract)* is defined as

> to draw the attention of (a person) away from something

However, these terms speak more to *attention*, rather than *enthusiasm*.

While not an adjective, you might consider **[dilettante](http://www.yourdictionary.com/dilettante)**

> a dabbler or a person who cultivates an interest without really committing or learning anything in depth.

SUPPLEMENT:

On further thought, the term **[fickle](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/fickle)** may be useful

> Characterized by erratic changeableness or instability, especially with regard to affections or attachments; capricious

Comment: but this word does not imply that person was enjoying the task in the beginning.

Comment: *Distractible* doesn't, but *dilettante* does. Check out more definitions of *dilettante* at [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=dilettante&ls=a).

Comment: Yes right. I posted that comment while **dilettante** was not added to your answer. You edited it afterwards :) I wonder why is **dilettante**  not a popular word? +1

Comment: I like dilettante for this.

Comment: fickle is another good one!

Answer (score 2):

A person who *continuously* and *repeatedly* expresses enthusiasm, confidence, and an almost excessive zeal at the start of any new task or adventure only to abandon it after a short time would appear to be [hyperthymic](http://counselorssoapbox.com/2012/06/07/hyperthymia-hyperthymic-personality-disorder-and-bipolar-disorder/)

> *Hyperthymic people are those people who have so much energy, do so many things and get so much done they annoy others. Goel, Terman and
>   Terman (2002) defined Hyperthymia as equivalent to Hypomania but
>   without the impairment. So if you lose control it is hypomania and you
>   get diagnosed with a mental illness (Bipolar.) But Hyperthymia by this
>   definition means you are able to hold it together.*

According to the limited number of experts in this field the following traits are also typical of a hyperthymic personlity:

- increased energy and productivity
- self-assurance, self-confidence
- strong will
- risk-taking/sensation seeking
- love of attention
- low threshold for boredom

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthymic_temperament)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about a person who likes to start new projects or quickly takes up new hobbies or fads, but quickly tires and moves on to the next thing - in other words, a person who seeks out novelty, is quickly bored by the familiar.

I can't quite think of a single word that describes them off the top of my head.

Some words that may help are:

Neophiliac - c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neophilia

Coolhunter - c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coolhunting

Novelty seeker - c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_seeking and http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Novelty-Seeking+Behavior

Comment: All of the suggested words suggest love of new things but they do not take into account the disinclination that follows.

Comment: Everything new soon becomes not-new, so I think it's implied in all these terms.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that there's a category shift involved. You're trying to find a word to describe a person's quality, rather than describing their (habitual?) attitude to something.

I'd suggest modifiers of 'enthusiasm', eg 'His enthusiasm wanes', 'Her enthusiasm diminuendos', 'Their enthusiasm diminishes', or any of the synonyms of 'decrease' [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/decrease?__utma=1.1944691844.1386704146.1391407952.1392722104.3&__utmb=1.40.9.1392723104111&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1392722104.3.3.utmcsr=thesaurus.com%7Cutmccn=%28referral%29%7Cutmcmd=referral%7Cutmcct=/browse/enthuse&__utmv=-&__utmk=61427756).

Comment: Hi! meet my friend John. He's a nice guy but "His enthusiasm wanes." Doesn't it give an impression that John is sexually impotent? :)

Comment: @SandeepDhamija I think it would depend on context and delivery.

Comment: I understand that. It's just that I found it funny and wanted to share. Thanks for your suggestions but I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija :) It's a really interesting question. I still stand by my distinction, though. All Jeffrey's examples are nouns - neither 'vacillatory' nor 'blows hot one minute, cold the other' would do - they convey change, but not rate of change. I still think you can only describe the enthusiasm, not the person, for this very reason.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija there's nothing sexual about _wanes_, the _moon_ wanes for heaven's sake!

Comment: +1 for _wanes_ but _diminuendos_ is [not a verb](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diminuendos) and has no meaning in English outside the context of music as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

A magpie-brain.

Magpies are renowned for their attraction to shiny objects. A magpie-brain is constantly distracted by shiny new ideas.

Answer (score -1):

He's a *thrillseeker* with a lack of *stick-to-it-iveness*.

This may be accompanied by a sense of self-entitlement, a brain wired for constant entertainment, and a poor work ethic.

All this is of course not a single adjective. I am hopeful it will provide you with some ideas to find the word you seek.

Comment: I have heard the term "stick-to-it-iveness" used, although I'm not sure it's been generally accepted into the language :)

Comment: To me it's more precise than "perseverance" or "hard-working" or even "dedicated".

Comment: I like it how your sensible, well thought answer is downvoted

Comment: You could upvote it!

Answer (score -1):

You want someone who is the opposite of determined, dogged and goal-oriented;
a good fit for this would be **flighty**.

The word is a little old-fashioned though, you'd be more likely to find it in an Agatha Christie book than a newspaper..

Comment: Flighty would tend to mean inconsistent

Comment: To me, this is a reaonable answer. I like your downvotes, though...