# Word for a person who starts a project, then starts another one?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who starts projects, doesn't ever finish, then starts another project?

Comment: You want a single word, or a phrase?

Comment: In college, you might call such a person an _incompletist_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for "a person who quickly gets interested and quickly loses interest"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86795/word-for-a-person-who-quickly-gets-interested-and-quickly-loses-interest). 'Dilettante' is given.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the generic word *mercurial* for this purpose. The word derives its name from the planet mercury which moves very fast across the zodiac, and generally gets associated with people who are fickle minded and change their decisions quickly.

Some other words derived from planets are *jovial* (derived from Jupiter) for humorous, *martian* (derived from Mars) for strong and *loony* (derived from Luna/Moon) for someone having mental issues.

Comment: [mercurial](https://www.google.com/search?q=mercurial+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8): (of a person) subject to sudden or unpredictable changes of mood or mind.

Answer (score 0):

Flighty. Or attention deficit. One who can't maintain interest or focus long enough to see something to completion. She flits from one thing to another, constantly distracted along the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Flibbertigibbet**

(A silly, scatterbrained, or garrulous person -- American Heritage)

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate word could be a dabbler. A dabbler is one who starts something say, a hobby but never gets to continue doing it.

Comment: I always think of a dabbler as being someone whose enthusiasm comes and goes (often of the _fair-weather_ kind). So they may complete a project but it'll take a while.